# Is SKU price in Google Analytics E-Commerce with or without VAT?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

In [ECommerce docu](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#item) it says just price. And I want to know if it should be the full price with VAT inclusive or the netto price.

Or does it not matter and it just depends on how our BI wants the data?